# What would be the best logic to detect if multiple SQL options were left enabled in a config file?

Tags: perl, ini

I am trying to figure the best logic to determine if the user of my script has left multiple SQL option enabled in the config file the reason is only one is supported.

The first idea I had was to use a simple variable that was set to either 0,1,2,3 and then read by the script to run the correct subroutine. Then I got to thinking if they was a way to have it done by whether the section existed in the config file, it was possible with the module I am using. But the problem I ran into now is if I have it determining which SQL software to use based on the existence of a certain config section doesn't that mean I have to have logic that says if "this" section and "that" section exist then error out? But then that would mean I would to take into account all combination of all section that pertain. Right?

Was the best way to approach this the first way that I had done it? or is there a better way?

I have included samples of my config file and the unfinished subroutine which the logic would be enclosed in. I would control the existence of the sections by commenting them out in the config file. I am writing in Perl by the way and I am using [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aIniFiles) for reading and writing to the INI file.

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

```
sub sql_option {
        if (config_file()->SectionExists('SQLite')) {
            sqlite_setup();
        } elsif (config_file()->SectionExists('MySQL')) {
            mysql_setup();
        } elsif (config_file()->SectionExists('PgSQL')) {
            pgsql_setup();
        } elsif (config_file()->SectionExists('MSSQL')) {
            mssql_setup();
        } else {
            print color 'red';
            print "No SQL server option defined!\n";
            print color 'reset';
            print "\n";
            die "Script halted!\n";
        } 
}
```

And the INI file:

```
[ESX]

host=esxi01.solignis.local
;port=
user=root
password=

[SQLite]

db=discovery.db


[MySQL]
host=sql01.solignis.local
;port=
user=root
password=

;[PgSQL]
;host=
;port=
;user=
;password=

;[MSSQL]
;host=
;port=
;user=
;password=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
my %sql_setup_functions = (
  SQLite => \&sqlite_setup,
  MySQL  => \&mysql_setup,
  PgSQL  => \&pgsql_setup,
  MSSQL  => \&mssql_setup,
);

sub sql_option
{
  my @engines = grep {
    config_file()->SectionExists($_)
  } keys %sql_setup_functions;

  unless (@engines == 1) {
    print color 'red';
    if (@engines) {
      print "Multiple SQL server options defined!\n";
      print "  $_\n" for sort @engines;
    } else {
      print "No SQL server option defined!\n";
    }
    print color 'reset';
    print "\n";
    die "Script halted!\n";
  } # end unless exactly 1 SQL engine

  # Call the setup function for the selected engine:
  $sql_setup_functions{$engines[0]}->();
} # end sql_option
```

Comment: I shortened it a bit more by using `grep` instead of `foreach`.

Comment: I added the code to my script, works perfect!. Took me a bit to understand how it works. I am still new to perl, I would have never though to do anything like this. Thanks a bunch.